# How to fix: UIView animations not restarting when returning to view controller

Tags: swift, animation, viewwillappear

I have a view that starts animating when a ViewController first opens. It works fine on initial launch, but when returning to the view after leaving the animation does not restart. The views are embedded in a Navigation controller

I tried placing the animation in several locations, including viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear and viewWillLayoutSubviews

I've placed a breakpoint in viewDidAppear and it does step through the code, but the animation does not restart.

```swift
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 20.0, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat, .curveLinear], animations: {
            self.scrollingView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -350, y: 0)
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        scrollingView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
```

Comment: Do You try put it in 
`viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIView Animations stop working after dismiss Modal View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771888/uiview-animations-stop-working-after-dismiss-modal-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `scrollingView` to its original position during the `segue`, because of the `UINavigationController` the 1st `UIViewController` does not go out of scope, aka it does not get instantiated again. Therefore when you come back to the 1st `UIViewController`, the `scrollingView` is still running the previous animation.

You need to restart the CGAffineTransform using the code below :

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     self.textView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
}
```